# Adding data- attribute to embedded Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add this attribute:

`data-show-url="<%= video_path(@video) %>"`

to the HTML that this embedded Ruby produces:

`<%= link_to 'video', video.video_url, :class => 'oembed'  %>`

What do I do in the embedded ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'video', video.video_url, :class => 'oembed', :'data-show-url' => video_path(@video) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a parameter you want to add, you can simply pass it like this:

```
<%= link_to 'video', video.video_url, :class => 'oembed', :data-show-url => video_path(@video) %>
```

You will get it as `params[:data-show-url]` and the link will be appended with `?data-show-url=value`.